# How can I redirect DNS queries to 127.0.0.53:53 with iptables?

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, forwarding

The problem is that I need to forward the incoming DNS query packets (from other computers) to `127.0.0.53` (**not** `127.0.0.1`).
I tried to redirect the queries to `127.0.0.1`, that worked fine, however it's not able to redirect them to `127.0.0.53`.

The IP address of the incoming interface is `10.66.66.1`, which is an virtual interface (`wg0`) of the wireguard VPN service.

The commands I used for forwarding to `127.0.0.1` were:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -p tcp -d 10.66.66.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:53
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -p udp -d 10.66.66.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:53
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i wg0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 10.66.66.1 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i wg0 -p udp -m udp -d 10.66.66.1 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

in which `wg0` was the interface of the wireguard VPN. That worked fine.

and the commands I used for forwarding to `127.0.0.53` were (the only difference was that I changed `127.0.0.1` to `127.0.0.53`, and the previous 6 rules were deleted before adding the following new rules):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -p tcp -d 10.66.66.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.53:53
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -p udp -d 10.66.66.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.53:53
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i wg0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 10.66.66.1 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i wg0 -p udp -m udp -d 10.66.66.1 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Besides, I enabled the port forwarding:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1 # physical interface
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.lo.route_localnet=1 # loopback interface
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.wg0.route_localnet=1 # wireguard interface
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

and the default policy of `INPUT`/`OUTPUT`/`FORWARD` chains was `ACCEPT`.

I have 2 questions:

1. how can I redirect the DNS queries to `127.0.0.53`?
2. I checked the filtered bytes of iptables (`iptables -L -v` and `iptables -t nat -L -v`), and why can't I see any packets filtered by the forward chain? even when the packets were redirected to `127.0.0.1` correctly?

The real problem I was trying to solve was that, the `stubby` service (encrypted DNS service) was listening at port `127.0.0.1:53`, and I can also set it to listen to `10.66.66.1:53`(the VPN interface), however, the stubby service ignored the static DNS bindings in `/etc/hosts`, which can be solved by sending DNS requests to `127.0.0.53` (`systemd-resolved` serrvice), and I needed to provide some static DNS bindings for all the VPN clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to use [systemd resolved](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html) as DNS server for your network.

Simply run [dnsmasq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq), which loads the contents of `/etc/hosts` so that local hostnames which do not appear in the global DNS can be resolved and also answers other DNS queries by forwarding them to the DNS server(s) of your choice (i.e. stubby).

Then push the IP-address where dnsmasq is listening as the resolver to your VPN users (or configure whatever forwarding you want to do for DNS traffic).

Comment: Thank you @Rob, that solved my problem and I will try it, and I think that may also speed up the DNS query response.And just for curiosity, I will still be waiting for a few while whether some one can answer why it's not able to redirect to `127.0.0.53`.